# PHP imap_open unable to check certificate

Tags: php, ssl, imap, starttls

I'm trying to connect to IMAP mailboxes using PHP imap_open() function. The error I get is "Certificate failure for *[my-mail.server.net]*: Unable to locate common name in certificate."

Trying with { *[my-mail.server.net]* :993/imap/ssl **/novalidate-cert** }, it works.

I suspect, PHP is not using the built-in roots. **My question: how can I convince PHP to use the built-in roots?**

Info: its about PHP 7.2 on FreeBSD 11.1 server, OpenSSL is installed and PHP is compiled with --with-openssl=shared

Thanks

Comment: "Unable to locate common name" seems to be an error in the certificate (or PHPs parsing).  That means it can't find a piece of data in the certificate it was looking for .  I don't think it's even gotten to validating the roots yet.

Comment: Thanks @Max, but this does not seem to be the case. In Apple Mail, everything works fine with the certificate. By the way, is it safe to assume, that Apple Mail actually validates the cert (can I check somehow)?

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure it does.  You can verify by putting a self-signed cert or some other bogus cert there and making sure it fails.